# How to update vs code without removing the previous version using .deb package in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, deb

I have download latest version of VS code 1.61 and when I click on .deb file, ubuntu ask to remove previous version of vs code and my fear is that will it remove my workspace and all settings if I delete the previously installed vs code.

[image: ubuntu softwares asking to remove vscode]

Ubuntu 20.04

someone can guide me please here

Comment: although I am able to update using command `sudo snap install code --classic` but it added another instance of vs code in ubuntu.

Comment: Is there a reason you really need that particular version?  The snap should be reasonably up-to-date.  You're kind of playing with fire, so the preemptive solution is to back up the data you are concerned about losing.  Nobody can give you a guarantee that you won't lose your data otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the previous version will not delete your workspace or your settings. Those are stored in your home directory separately from the program files. The package manager will only touch the files that it installed, not files that VS Code created.